# Replicate the default button back segue from a table view clel

Tags: swift, tableview, uitableview

I have 3 ViewControllers, ViewController A brings in View Controller B. In ViewController B I have 3 buttons, and each segue over to ViewController C using the show segue animation. On ViewController C there is a tableview as well as a nav bar at the top with a back button that as you would expect goes back to ViewController B. When I control drag from my custom UICell and create a segue way back to View Controller B the back button that is in ViewController B now goes back to ViewController C, which is not what I want. Is it possible to replicate the back button Method from View Controller C, so that when I select a cell it just returns back to ViewController B, that way the back button on ViewController B goes back to the ViewController A.

Thanks for the suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference I found that this is what I was looking to do:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("did select")

    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

}